# Python multiprocessing crashes docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

There is simple python multiprocessing code that works like a charm, when I run it in console:

```
# mp.py
import multiprocessing as mp


def do_smth():
    print('something')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    p = ctx.Process(target=do_smth, args=tuple())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Result:

```
> $ python3 mp.py
something
```

Then I've created a simple Docker container with Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
```

And docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  bug:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    command: su -c "python3.6 forever.py"
```

Where `forever.py` is:

```
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    while True:
        sleep(1.0)
        i += 1
        print(f'hello {i:3}')
```

Now I run `forever.py` with docker compose:

```
> $ docker-compose build && docker-compose up 
...
some output
...
Attaching to mpbug_bug_1
bug_1  | hello   1
bug_1  | hello   2
bug_1  | hello   3
bug_1  | hello   4
```

Up to this moment everything is good and understandable. But when I'm trying to run `mp.py` in the docker container it crashes without any message:

```
> $ docker exec -it mpbug_bug_1 /bin/bash
root@09779ec47f9d:/app# python mp.py 
something
root@09779ec47f9d:/app# %
```

Gist with the code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ilalex/83649bf21ef50cb74a2df5db01686f18

Can you explain why docker container is crashed and how to do it without crashing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Doesn't look like it crashed. Just looks like it exited. Containers exit when they're done executing their scripts.

Comment: @Neil But `forever.py` can't be exited without crash. Or can?

Comment: If you are `exec`-ing *into* the container that `forever.py` is running in, then you are stopping that process and starting `bash`

Comment: @C.Nivs When `exec`-ing into the container, logs show that `forever.py` is still working and prints hello-message until I run `mp.py`

Comment: Hm okay. One more question, what is the output of "docker ps" a) Before your exec in and run mp.py and b) After the containers exits.

Comment: Also, just to mention the obvious, running as daemon will probably resolve the issue.

Comment: @Neil `docker ps` before run:

0dee02229759        mpbug_bug                   "su -c 'python3.6 fo…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   mpbug_bug_1

`docker ps -a | grep bug` after:

0dee02229759        mpbug_bug                               "su -c 'python3.6 fo…"   2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 56 seconds ago  mpbug_bug_1

Comment: @Neil Nope, running as a daemon doesn't resolve the issue. Container has stopped after run mp.py.

Comment: BTW, running script without multiprocessing doesn't stop container.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for a quick fix, do not use `spawn` start method, and/or do not use `su -c ...`, both are unnecessary IMO. change to:

```
p = mp.Process(target=do_smth, args=tuple())
```

or you could start container with `--init` option.

with `spawn` start method, Python will also start a [semaphore tracker process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) to prevent semaphore leaking, you could see this process by pausing `mp.py` in the middle, it looks like:

```
472   463 /usr/local/bin/python3 -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main;main(3)
```

this process is started by `mp.py` but exited after `mp.py`, thus it will not be reaped by `mp.py`, but is supposed to be reaped by `init` by design.

the problem is there is no `init` in this container(namespace), instead of `init`, PID 1 is `su -c`, therefore the dead semaphore tracker process is adopted by `su`.

it appears that `su` consider the dead child process is the command process(`forever.py`) mistakenly, without checking the relationship, so `su` exit blindly, as PID 1 exit, kernel kills all other processes in the container, including `forever.py`.

this behavior could be observed with `strace`:

```
docker run --security-opt seccomp:unconfined --rm -it ex_bug strace -e trace=process -f su -c 'python3 forever.py'
```

will output error message like:

```
strace: Exit of unknown pid 14 ignored
```

ref: [Docker and the PID 1 zombie reaping problem (phusion.nl)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8916785)

Answer (score 3):

`mp.py` doesn't look like an equivalent of `forever.py`. `mp.py` will run new worker process, which will just print `something` and then it will exit => `join()` in the main process will exit immediately, when this worker process is done.

Better equivalent of `forever.py`: worker process prints hello message in the infinite loop and main process will be waiting for this worker process exit in `join()` - `forever-mp.py`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

def do_smth():
    i = 0
    while True:
        sleep(1.0)
        i += 1
        print(f'hello {i:3}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context("spawn")
    p = ctx.Process(target=do_smth, args=tuple())
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Updated `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  bug:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    command: su -c "python3.6 forever-mp.py"
```

Test:

```
$ docker-compose build && docker-compose up 
...
some output
...
Attaching to multiprcs_bug_1_72681117a752
bug_1_72681117a752 | hello   1
bug_1_72681117a752 | hello   2
bug_1_72681117a752 | hello   3
bug_1_72681117a752 | hello   4
```

Check processes in the container:

```
$ docker top multiprcs_bug_1_72681117a752
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                38235               38217               0                   21:36               ?                   00:00:00            su -c python3.6 forever-mp.py
root                38297               38235               0                   21:36               ?                   00:00:00            python3.6 forever-mp.py
root                38300               38297               0                   21:36               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main;main(3)
root                38301               38297               0                   21:36               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/local/bin/python3.6 -c from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(tracker_fd=4, pipe_handle=6) --multiprocessing-fork
```

Comment: Of course they are not equivalent to each other. The question is about unexpectedly stopping of container when we run python multiprocessing. See the gist for steps to reproduce.

Comment: Your `mp.py` doesn't run forever - it will print 'something' and it will finish with exit code 0. So why you are expecting that container will be running forever?

Comment: I expect that `forever.py` will not stop running when I run `mp.py`. There is no logical connection between them. Why container stops `forever.py`? That's my question.

Comment: Can you reproduce stopping of `forever.py` when you run simultaneously `mp.py`?

Comment: No, I can't reproduce it.